# Load p12 file in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am developing an application that communicates with Google API but I need to provide a private key that is stored in a p12 file. What is the best practice to include the p12 file in an Laravel 4 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using Google APIs with a p12 file but if you just need the contents of the file, I'd do it like this.

Put the the file inside `app/storage/keys` (you'll have to create the `keys` directory)

Then read the contents

```
$key = file_get_contents(storage_path() . '/keys/google.p12');
```

Comment: I solved to create folder with the key in the application folder and then I used File::get(app_path() . /locationtokey). But i think it is indeed nicer to put it in the storage. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: could you please tell me, what should be the content of p12 file? I created client id and client secret..

Comment: @lukasgeiter.. what is the key.. I'm confused

Comment: in your case, what is the content of google.p12... could you explain it?

Comment: @users4393829 I don't know, as I said I've never used a p12 file